# Xamarin.iOS UITableView isn't updated by ReloadData()

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have **UITableView** with custom cells. Code for cell:

```
public partial class SaleTableViewCell : MvxTableViewCell
    {
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("SaleTableViewCell");
        public static readonly UINib Nib = UINib.FromName("SaleTableViewCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);

        public SaleTableViewCell(IntPtr handle)
            : base(handle)
        {
            this.DelayBind(() =>
            {
                var set = this.CreateBindingSet<SaleTableViewCell, SaleItem>();
                set.Bind(IdLabel).To(vm => vm.ProductKey);
                set.Bind(NameLabel).To(vm => vm.Description);
                set.Bind(QuantityLabel).To(vm => vm.Quantity);
                set.Bind(PriceLabel).To(vm => vm.Price);
                set.Bind(DiscountLabel).To(vm => vm.DiscountAmount);
                set.Bind(TotalLabel).To(vm => vm.Total);
                set.Apply();
            });
        }


        public static SaleTableViewCell Create()
        {
            return (SaleTableViewCell)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
        }
    }
```

I'm using **MvxSimpleTableViewSource**:

```
var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource(TableView, SaleTableViewCell.Key, SaleTableViewCell.Key);
TableView.Source = source;
```

But when I'm trying to change any property of **SaleItem** (for example *Quantity*) my TableView isn't updated even if I directly call `TableView.ReloadData();`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post the code for your SaleItem class as well as the ViewModel that is associated with your TableView. In general, once you update the property of a cell, you need to call RaisePropertyChanged on the ObservableCollection that is bound to your ListView to ReloadData.

Answer (score 0):

`SaleItem` needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
Then you can change its properties and you´ll see the results in the table cell.

The easiest way to do that is by using this nuget: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged, but you can write the implementation yourself as well.